# Docker-compose and race condition on container depending on other container

Tags: java, spring, docker

I have `docker-compose` which will start multiple containers of Java SpringBoot microservices and one of them, which depends on two others, will fail to start with something like race condition:

```
Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitConnectionFactory': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:208)
```

When I will stop it and run it manually it will pick up. When `docker-compose` will have set `restart: on-failure` for that service it will pick up on 3rd restart.

Any tips how to handle such of problem?

Comment: Have you tried using [depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on)

Comment: Please see here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry

Comment: @J.F. As I have put in the OP I'm using `depends_on` and that is not solving my problem for some reason

Comment: "Restart until all the dependencies are up" is the way you'd do this in Kubernetes, FWIW, and doing it this way in Compose too is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please see chapter **7.4** here, it really works:
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_client.html

Answer (score 0):

Usually, depends_on is enough. Nevertheless, sometimes it may not work properly. Once I heard about this issue and the recommendation was to use the `healthcheck` docker option, available at docker v2.3. See guide [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/).

I am adding an example using a healthcheck to guarantee the database is up. So, only after the healthcheck is ok, they will startup the other apps.

```
[...]
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'mysql -uroot --database=<db-name> --password=<password> --execute="SELECT 
  count(table_name) > 0 FROM information_schema.tables;" --skip-column-names -B']
  interval: 10s
  timeout: 10s
  retries: 4
```